# Python Sum dictionary elements (better pythonic way)

Tags: python, dictionary

I wrote simple few lines of code to sum elements of python dictionary to make it uniqe.

```
test =  [{'id': 3L, 'category': 'BOOK', 'information': 'abcdefghijk', 'name': 'test', 'sum': 5},
      {'id': 3L, 'category': 'BOOK', 'information': 'abcdefghijk', 'name': 'test', 'sum': 1},
      {'id': 3L, 'category': 'BOOK', 'information': 'abcdefghijk', 'name': 'test', 'sum': 3},
      {'id': 4L, 'category': 'BOOK', 'information': 'abcdefghijk', 'name': 'test2', 'sum': 1},
      {'id': 4L, 'category': 'BOOK', 'information': 'abcdefghijk', 'name': 'test2', 'sum': 1},
      {'id': 5L, 'category': 'BOOK', 'information': 'abcdefghijk', 'name': 'test4', 'sum': 1},
      {'id': 6L, 'category': 'BOOK', 'information': 'abcdefghijk', 'name': 'test5', 'sum': 1}]

newlist = []
newdict = {}

for dict_item in test:

    pixel = dict_item['id']
    country = dict_item['category']
    ac = dict_item['information']
    name = dict_item['name']
    sum = dict_item['sum']

    if newdict.has_key(pixel):

        pos = newdict[pixel]
        newlist[pos] = {'id': pixel, 'category': country, 'information': ac, 'name': name, 'sum': (newlist[pos]['sum']+sum)}
    else:
        newlist.append(dict_item)
        newdict[pixel] = len(newlist) -1

print newlist
```

Result of my sum:

```
   [{'category': 'BOOK', 'information': 'abcdefghijk', 'sum': 9, 'id': 3L, 'name': 'test'},{'category': 'BOOK', 'information': 'abcdefghijk', 'sum': 2, 'id': 4L, 'name': 'test2'},{'category': 'BOOK', 'information': 'abcdefghijk', 'sum': 2, 'id': 5L, 'name': 'test5'}]
```

Is there a better way to sum this dictionary to sum id to be unique?

Comment: tbh I don't understand the downvotes, this seems like a good question to me. It would be constructive if the downvoters could elaborate.

Comment: Don't use `has_key`, use `in`; `has_key` is deprecated in 3.x and `in` is more idiomatic.

Comment: What exactly to keep in output data for inputs with the same `id` but with different `category`, `information`, `name`, …?

Comment: Where do the new id's come from?

Comment: Would you please add more detail how output is like this?

Comment: @Lisa it would be a good question if more details comes for sample output

Comment: I added good input guys :)

Comment: So, just to make this clear: Is it a typo, or on purpose that the two dicts with id `5L` have different names and you keep the one that's occurring last?

Comment: Now you have an id that has a different  name that was the same before your edit, is test4 a mistake?

Comment: Yep its a mistake, the id should be diffrent :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test =  [{'id': 3937L, 'category': 'BOOK', 'information': 'abcdefghijk', 'name': 'test', 'sum': 5},
      {'id': 3937L, 'category': 'BOOK', 'information': 'abcdefghijk', 'name': 'test', 'sum': 1},
      {'id': 3937L, 'category': 'BOOK', 'information': 'abcdefghijk', 'name': 'test', 'sum': 3},
      {'id': 4215L, 'category': 'BOOK', 'information': 'abcdefghijk', 'name': 'test2', 'sum': 1},
      {'id': 4215L, 'category': 'BOOK', 'information': 'abcdefghijk', 'name': 'test2', 'sum': 1},
      {'id': 4217L, 'category': 'BOOK', 'information': 'abcdefghijk', 'name': 'test4', 'sum': 1},
      {'id': 4218L, 'category': 'BOOK', 'information': 'abcdefghijk', 'name': 'test5', 'sum': 1}]

dct = {}

for d in test:
    if d["id"] in dct:
        dct[d["id"]]["sum"] += d["sum"]
    else:
        dct[d["id"]] = d.copy()

from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(dct.values())
```

Output matches running your own code:

```
[{'category': 'BOOK',
  'id': 4217L,
  'information': 'abcdefghijk',
  'name': 'test4',
  'sum': 1},
 {'category': 'BOOK',
  'id': 3937L,
  'information': 'abcdefghijk',
  'name': 'test',
  'sum': 9},
 {'category': 'BOOK',
  'id': 4218L,
  'information': 'abcdefghijk',
  'name': 'test5',
  'sum': 1},
 {'category': 'BOOK',
  'id': 4215L,
  'information': 'abcdefghijk',
  'name': 'test2',
  'sum': 2}]
```

You can simply call `dict.copy()` to create new dicts, you don't need to create a new dict manually each time.

Comment: Thx i like your answer

Comment: @moviss, no worries, dict.copy is pretty efficient when you want to replicate  dict,  if you had other mutable objects as values you would need `copy.deepcopy`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to recreate the entire dictionary with all its keys and values. Just use `dict` to create a copy of the original dictionary or add to the sum of the dictionary existing in the list. Also, you can derive the `newlist` from the `newdict`.

```
newdict = {} # or collections.OrderedDict() if order is important
for dict_item in test:
    pixel = dict_item['id']
    if pixel in newdict:
        newdict[pixel]["sum"] += dict_item['sum']
    else:
        newdict[pixel] = dict(dict_item)
newlist = list(newdict.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.  Basically, combine all dicts that have the same id.  I'm also sticking with a dict instead of a list so that you can easily pick out the mapping from key to values.

```
squashed = {}
for inner in test:
    key = inner['id']
    del inner['id']
    if key in squashed:
        squashed[key]['sum'] += inner['sum']
    else:
        squashed[key] = inner
```

Comment: This will modify the original dictionaries. Not sure if this is intended. Also, why do you remove the `id` field?

Comment: Good point!   I removed the id filed since its unnecessary to store the id twice, as the key and in the dictionary again.  But maybe for OPs purpose, it'd be better/easier to keep it in the dict.